# Updating collection in entity throws "Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table"

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, automapper, crud, aspnetboilerplate

When I try to update the following entity, if any of the items in the collection already exist in the db (ie already has a ID value assigned) the sql statement generates an insert for that record and includes the ID field in the insert, but the ID is an Auto Increment field and hence yields a "Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table".

Entities:

```
public class Event : FullAuditedEntity<int>, IMustHaveTenant
{
    public const int MaxNameLength = 128;
    public const int MaxDescriptionLength = 2048;

    public virtual int TenantId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(MaxNameLength)]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(MaxDescriptionLength)]
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime DateTimeStart { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime DateTimeEnd { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("EventId")]
    public virtual ICollection<EventOutlet> Outlets { get; set; }

 }

public class EventOutlet : CreationAuditedEntity<int>, IMustHaveTenant
{
    public int TenantId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("EventId")]
    public virtual Event AssignedEvent { get;  set; }
    public virtual int EventId { get;  set; }

    [ForeignKey("OutletId")]
    public virtual Outlet AssignedOutlet { get; set; }
    public virtual int OutletId { get; set; }

}
```

CRUD Update call:

```
public override async Task<EventDto> Update(EventDto input)
{
    CheckUpdatePermission();

    var evnt = await _eventManager.GetA(input.Id);

    MapToEntity(input, evnt);

    CheckErrors(await _eventManager.UpdateA(evnt));

    return await Get(input);
}
```

In the following case there are 2 records in the EventOutlet collection, one that already exists in the db, the other is a new entry. The following sql statement is generated to update the entity. It tries the insert the existing record in the collection supplying the ID field which causes the error, ie this should be an update statement, then it inserts the new record in the collection without the ID field, which is correct. Then updates the entity with its fields which is correct.

What am I missing in the update routine for the existing items in the collection to be updated rather than attempting to be inserted again.

Cheers

```
exec sp_executesql N'SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO [AppEventOutlets] ([Id], [CreationTime], [CreatorUserId], [EventId], [OutletId], [TenantId])
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5);
INSERT INTO [AppEventOutlets] ([CreationTime], [CreatorUserId], [EventId], [OutletId], [TenantId])
VALUES (@p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10);
SELECT [Id]
FROM [AppEventOutlets]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = 1 AND [Id] = scope_identity();

UPDATE [AppEvents] SET [CreationTime] = @p11, [CreatorUserId] = @p12, [DateTimeEnd] = @p13, [DateTimeStart] = @p14, [DeleterUserId] = @p15, [DeletionTime] = @p16, [Description] = @p17, [IsDeleted] = @p18, [LastModificationTime] = @p19, [LastModifierUserId] = @p20, [Name] = @p21, [TenantId] = @p22
WHERE [Id] = @p23;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

',N'@p0 int,@p1 datetime2(7),@p2 bigint,@p3 int,@p4 int,@p5 int,@p6 datetime2(7),@p7 bigint,@p8 int,@p9 int,@p10 int,@p23 int,@p11 datetime2(7),@p12 bigint,@p13 datetime2(7),@p14 datetime2(7),@p15 bigint,@p16 datetime2(7),@p17 nvarchar(2048),@p18 bit,@p19 datetime2(7),@p20 bigint,@p21 nvarchar(128),@p22 int',@p0=2009,@p1='2018-05-18 14:46:11.4780000',@p2=4,@p3=1,@p4=1003,@p5=2,@p6='2018-05-24 22:10:36.7558598',@p7=4,@p8=1,@p9=1008,@p10=2,@p23=1,@p11='2018-05-09 17:03:49.6870000',@p12=4,@p13='2018-05-11 07:24:38',@p14='2018-05-10 07:24:35',@p15=NULL,@p16=NULL,@p17=N'Friday',@p18=0,@p19='2018-05-24 22:10:46.7874563',@p20=4,@p21=N'Event 1',@p22=2
```

Comment: Use `ObjectMapper.Map(input, event);` instead of `MapToEntity(input, evnt)`

Comment: [AutoMapper.Collection](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection)

Comment: Thanks vivek, I've changed it to use ObjectMapper.Map, but I still get the same error. The event object gets the collection populated, and the existing records have the ID populated and new entries in the collection have an ID of zero, yet the eventmanager Update routine still generates sql statement to insert the existing records including the ID field rather than using an update ?

Comment: Can you please try entry.Property("ID").IsModified = false;

Comment: Sorry, I’m fairly new to all this, I’m not familiar with the entry. Property method and can’t get it to compile, is there a library I need to add to add this statement?

Comment: you say there's EventOutlet collection but I see only "EventDto input" in Update() method. Beside show the code of EventManager.Get() method. I think your entity is not being tracked by EF. Are you adding .WithNoTrack() to the query?

Comment: EventDto is defined as follows:

[AutoMapFrom(typeof(Event))]
    public class EventDto : FullAuditedEntityDto<int>
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateTimeStart { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateTimeEnd { get; set; }

        public ICollection<EventOutletDto> Outlets { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Update method as follows:

Update method is as follows:

        public override async Task<EventDto> Update(EventDto input)
        {
            CheckUpdatePermission();

            var evnt = await _eventRepository.GetAllIncluding(x => x.Outlets).FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == input.Id);//await _eventManager.GetA(input.Id);

            ObjectMapper.Map(input, evnt);
             
            CheckErrors(await _eventManager.UpdateA(evnt));

            return await Get(input);
        }

Comment: You need to handle collections separately: [aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate#3393](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/3393)

Comment: aaron do you have an example of how to achieve this using automapper.collection ?